# Windows Phone data binding: cross-thread

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, multithreading

we have a problem with data binding on windows phone (using xaml). i have created a simple example, which should allow to reproduce the problem.
Here is our model-class:

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int value = 0;
    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Data()
    {
        var t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Value += 1;
            }
        }));
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

which uses a thread to update the value-property and fire the PropertyChanged-event.

Now i want to bind this value-property to a gui control:

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
    </Grid>

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new Data();
    }
```

when the value first changes (and the PropertyChanged-event gets fired) the data binding system tries to copy the value of Data.Value to TextBlock.Text, which results in an invalid cross-thread exception, as this event is not fired on the ui thread.

my question: shouldn't the .NET databinding framework recognize that i'm binding to a ui control and perform the thread switching itself? i know that i can simply use a dispatcher to fire the PropertyChanged-event on the main thread, but i'd like to have my model-class more seperated from the gui component.
is there a better solution to this problem? i am unable to use the DependencyObject approach, because our core project (which contains the model class) should run on Windows Phone AND Android, and Android doesn't support the System.Windows-namespace.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be to store a reference to the dispatcher on your view model and only use it to execute the property changed event if it is not null. Then you can set the dispatcher property in your VM's constructor.

Comment: Deployment.Current.Dispatcher

Comment: As i posted in my original question, we do know that this is a possibility. In the full .NET framework there is no need to use a dispatcher, because the databinding switches to the main thread automatically. I wanted to know if (or how) i can i achieve this behaviour on windows phone (or silverlight for android).

Comment: @Will as Deployment lies in System.Windows, it is not a possible solution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.deployment.current(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @Dominik [it says its part of WP7; the Current property has a phone next to it.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.deployment%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: @Will please read my question: "i am unable to use the DependencyObject approach, because our core project (which contains the model class) should run on Windows Phone AND Android, and Android doesn't support the System.Windows-namespace." (this also applies to System.Windows.Deployment)

Comment: @DominikvonWeber: Aaah... my bad.  Okay, so static references won't work.  What about wrapping the call and using dependency injection?

Comment: Since this is quite an old I'd like to ask if you found a proper solution for the issue? Btw, how it is possible to develop in .NET for the Android platform?

Answer (score 0):

I do like this:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void PropertyEventChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null) return;

        if (Application.OpenForms.Count > 0 && Application.OpenForms[0].InvokeRequired)
            Application.OpenForms[0].Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))));
        else
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```